# Passing parameter by URL

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC 3.0. I want Passing parameter with URL. It works. But if my parameter value is like shahin & karina. Then it count as a two value beacuse of &. I want to inculed & as a vlue. How can I do that. Please, Anyone has solved this kind of problem.

For example:
My controller function is:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{}
```

html code

```
<a href="/stat?name=shahin & karina">
```

Form the controller I got only name value is: shahin
But I need Name value is: shahin & karina

Thanks advance..

Comment: Try using a %26 instead of & and %20 instead of spaces

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you would need to do is URL encode the ampersand (and possibly the space character).

Try something like this -

```
<a href="/stat?name=shahin%20%26%20karina">
```

- `%20` is an encoded space character.
- `%26` - is the encoded ampersand character.

I have absolutely zero knowledge or experience with `asp.net` but I'm fairly sure that there are native URL encoding functions...

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the URL. There is surely a library for it in .NET.

Similar tools:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Cheers
HH

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode '&' as an HTML entity.

```
<a href="/stat?name=shahin%20%26%20karina" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the html code as:

```
<a href="/stat?shahin%20%26%20karina" />
```

`%20` is a url-encoded space and `%26` is the url-encoded ampersand

You can use [this tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to try encoding different strings (in this example, you would encode "shahin & karina")